# Import Firebase Analytics in Typescript file

Tags: typescript, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log server-side events but I'm unable to use Firebase (Google) Analytics.
I import functions and admin as follows:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

but I cannot find anything similar to import firebase analytics, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I found this post answering that it's not possible:
[Frank van Puffelen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689319/1095610)

Anyone correcting this answer is welcome!