# Firebase Analytics Server Side

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, measurement-protocol

Firebase Client (JS) supports Firebase Analytics.
In there, I use the method `logEvent` to log my events to GA v2 and see great funnels.

However, some events, like database events, or HTTP requests coming from a 3rd party aren't tracked by the client, obviously, so we are looking at how to log events from the firebase admin SDK, or just via a Google Analytics API.

It, unfortunately, seems like the "google analytics measurement protocol" used in firebase analytics doesn't have an API. Official or not.

I am looking for a canonical response to know if it is or is not possible to log events (or page views) from the firebase admin SDK or generally using whatever API / library in Node.JS

An immediate solution was to try to use the firebase client SDK in Node, however from this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup It seems like if I instantiate the firebase client SDK on a Node.js server, I cannot use the analytics feature.

**Edit:**

While there are other similar questions, they are over a year old, and the responses might not be valid anymore.

- [Firebase analytics log events with cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688942/firebase-analytics-log-events-with-cloud-functions)
- [Can I track my Firebase function in Google Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282817/can-i-track-my-firebase-function-in-google-analytics)
- [Firebase - log events from server side cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026739/firebase-log-events-from-server-side-cloud-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Firebase analytics from remote REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355752/firebase-analytics-from-remote-rest-api)

Comment: No, it's currently not possible.