# Log events with firebase admin nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, events, firebase-analytics, firebase-admin

How can I log events in firebase analytics using firebase admin sdk for nodejs ? I would like my backend to log an event in firebase analytics when it runs a specific action.

Comment: There is no server-side API for sending Analytics events in the Firebase SDK. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60936743/firebase-analytics-server-side and https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/137

Comment: This is really sad to hear. There are very good use cases to extend logging by server side events, e.g. in trials in app purchases that converted into subscriptions (cross-platform, Firebase is only able to track it for iOS, not Android/web) and server side events in general. I hope this can be seen in the admin-sdk soon :-)