# How to log Firebase Analytics event via Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I need log some Firebase Analytic event by Node.js Cloud Function (for example user purchase). How I can do this with API?

Puf say it now possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46283769

But this only show how to generate report. How I can log specific event for user with API?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/google-analytics-firebase#:~:text=Google%20Analytics%20for%20Firebase%20provides,are%20supported%20by%20Cloud%20Functions.) ?

Comment: I might indeed have missed a link in my answer there. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events. I also updated the linked answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for reply! But how we can call this `logEvent function` you mention? Is `wrapped in the Node.js Admin SDK`? I can not find doc showing how to do